# Adding missing dates with values as 0 using sql

Tags: sql, postgresql, date

Input Data:

```
+---+---------------+-------------+
|   | checkout_date | item_demand |
+---+---------------+-------------+
| 0 | 2022-08-02    |           1 |
| 1 | 2022-08-05    |           2 |
| 2 | 2022-08-07    |           1 |
| 3 | 2022-08-08    |           1 |
| 4 | 2022-08-09    |           1 |
| 5 | 2022-08-12    |           2 |
+---+---------------+-------------+
```

Output Data :

```
+---+---------------+-------------+
|   | checkout_date | item_demand |
+---+---------------+-------------+
| 0 | 2022-08-02    |           1 |
| 1 | 2022-08-03    |           0 |
| 1 | 2022-08-04    |           0 |
| 1 | 2022-08-05    |           2 |
| 1 | 2022-08-06    |           0 |
| 2 | 2022-08-07    |           1 |
| 3 | 2022-08-08    |           1 |
| 4 | 2022-08-09    |           1 |
| 1 | 2022-08-10    |           0 |
| 1 | 2022-08-11    |           0 |
| 5 | 2022-08-12    |           2 |
+---+---------------+-------------+
```

Filling the Dates with 0 in item demand, how to achieve this, I'm new to SQL

Comment: There is probably a better way but when I really had to do it in SQL I used to create a table with dates in and do an outer join on it.

Answer (score 2):

It's not so clear how calculated first column, but except this you can use `generate_series` with `left join` real data:

```
with dates as (
  select generate_series(
      (select min(checkout_date) from t),
      (select max(checkout_date) from t),
      '1 day'
  ) date
) 
select 
    date,
    coalesce(item_demand, 0) item_demand
from dates left join t on date = checkout_date
```

[online sql editor](https://sqlize.online/sql/psql13/1706663a2bd8d3f035c484da98e16bbf/)